Internal Server Error by uploading django project to apache server
Try to upload my djnago project to apache2 server and at the begging hadn't an access(error 403). After somehow solved problem got new one Internal Server Error.
/var/log/apache2/error.log:
[Sat Sep 07 22:05:50.292291 2024] [core:warn] [pid 74852:tid 129319697659776] AH00045: child process 74853 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sat Sep 07 22:05:50.292335 2024] [core:warn] [pid 74852:tid 129319697659776] AH00045: child process 74854 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sat Sep 07 22:05:52.294434 2024] [core:error] [pid 74852:tid 129319697659776] AH00046: child process 74853 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Sat Sep 07 22:05:52.294476 2024] [core:error] [pid 74852:tid 129319697659776] AH00046: child process 74854 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Sat Sep 07 22:05:53.295592 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 74852:tid 129319697659776] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Sep 07 22:08:55.562107 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 76122:tid 129486358599552] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 07 22:08:55.562464 2024] [core:notice] [pid 76122:tid 129486358599552] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myip

    WSGIScriptAlias / /my/directory/my_project/wsgi.py

    <Directory /my/directory/my_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /my/directory/my_project
    <Directory /my/directory/my_project>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

If anyone needs more information, I'll be happy to provide it
I've already tried some commands with sudo chmod -R 755 and sudo chown -R www-data:www-data, but it didn't work for me

That error.log you copied is useless, it only shows that the http server is restarted. Please copy the relevant sections that contain the actual errors. Note that the log file might have been rotated in the mean time.

Why did you implement two identical <Directory ...> section in that configuration?

I just see that the error.log file you posted is the wrong one ...That is the main log file. But inside that virtual host you configure a different one: ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_error.log So please add the relevant content you find in that log file to the question.
